# Convert MySQL query to Informix

Tags: mysql, sql, informix

I used following query to retrieve information from a mysql table.

```
SELECT ACCESS_TOKEN,
       AUTHZ_USER,
       TOKEN_SCOPE,
       TOKEN_STATE,
       REFRESH_TOKEN_TIME_CREATED,
       REFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY_PERIOD,
       IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN_SELECTED.TOKEN_ID
FROM
    (SELECT ACCESS_TOKEN,
            AUTHZ_USER, 
            TOKEN_STATE, 
            REFRESH_TOKEN_TIME_CREATED,
            REFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY_PERIOD, 
            TOKEN_ID 
     FROM IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN
     WHERE CONSUMER_KEY = "" 
       AND REFRESH_TOKEN = "" 
     ORDER BY TIME_CREATED DESC
     LIMIT 1) AS IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN_SELECTED 
  JOIN IDN_OAUTH2_SCOPE_ASSOCIATION 
WHERE IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN_SELECTED.TOKEN_ID =
IDN_OAUTH2_SCOPE_ASSOCIATION.TOKEN_ID;
```

How can I get the same result in a Informix database with same tables?

Comment: ANSI SQL requires an ON for each JOIN, but here you have a WHERE instead. Just change the last WHERE to ON.

Comment: It worked, added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same can be done by converting 'LIMIT 1' to 'FIRST 1' and 'WHERE' of Join to 'ON',

```
SELECT ACCESS_TOKEN, AUTHZ_USER, TOKEN_SCOPE, TOKEN_STATE,
       REFRESH_TOKEN_TIME_CREATED, REFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY_PERIOD,
       IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN_SELECTED.TOKEN_ID
  FROM (SELECT FIRST 1 ACCESS_TOKEN, AUTHZ_USER, TOKEN_STATE,
               REFRESH_TOKEN_TIME_CREATED, REFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY_PERIOD,
               TOKEN_ID
          FROM IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN
         WHERE CONSUMER_KEY = "" AND REFRESH_TOKEN = ""
         ORDER BY TIME_CREATED DESC) AS IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN_SELECTED
  JOIN IDN_OAUTH2_SCOPE_ASSOCIATION
    ON IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN_SELECTED.TOKEN_ID = IDN_OAUTH2_SCOPE_ASSOCIATION.TOKEN_ID;
```